# What are the reasons Envoy needs admin privileges, and can it be avoid?

Tags: load-balancing, istio

I want to use Envoy as an L7 Load balancer implementation running alongside kubernetes, but I cannot give it admin access, as that is a security problem I have to worry about. Some research tells me that Envoy needs admin access to modify some IP tables, but do the other containers in the pod also need admin access? If so, why? And is that something for which a workaround exists?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the instructions, you should create iptables rules with Envoy user UID (like in Istio).

`sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-port 5001`

`sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-port 5001 -m owner '!' --uid-owner ${Envoy_User_UID}`

In order to run this rule, a new user with `${Envoy_User_UID}` needs to be created before launching Envoy. Envoy then needs to be run under this user id, so that packets from Envoy don't get redirected to themselves.

On the other hand, you can use Ambassador - it is an open source distribution of Envoy designed for Kubernetes.

How to deploy and configure Ambassador you can find in [Envoy as an API Gateway in Kubernetes](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/start/distro/ambassador) instruction.

You can find more details on [Setup IP tables rules to redirect inbound/outbound traffic to Envoy sidecar](https://github.com/amalgam8/amalgam8/issues/482) page.
Also, [Use Envoy as tcp/http proxy for all outbound traffic](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/3078) could be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If Ambassador is an open source distribution of envoy, wouldn't I face the same problems?

Comment: Always welcome! Based on instruction you should not face any issues.